# How do I define and plot a function involving random variable?

Tags: graphics, function-construction, probability-or-statistics

I am struggling to define and and plot the following function:

$\qquad \sin(x) + 0.15\,u$

where u is a uniform random variable in the range [-1, 1].

How can I define such a function and then plot it for $x$ over the range [0, 500]?

Comment: Take a look at [UniformDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniformDistribution.html) and [TransformedDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html). I think it may help you.

Comment: This is not really a well-defined problem.  You are wanting to plot a realisation of a random process.  Do you have one value of `u` for all values of `x`? Or do you have an independent value of `u` for every real value of `x`?  If the latter, when you plot it (at any resolution) you will only see a vertical bar around the curve.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a function with randomness almost exactly like defining a regular (deterministic) function:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + 0.15*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Between 0 and 500:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 500}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0]

data = Table[{x, 
    Sin[x] + 0.15*RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]]}, {x, 0,
     500, 0.25}];

ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much guys!!